# Should I hear from a prospective employer after my physical?

Tags: hiring-process, resignation, human-resources, onboarding

I accepted a job offer in healthcare a couple of months ago. I have done all onboarding, and have my orientation scheduled by HR in July. I went for my pre employment physical almost 3 weeks ago but haven’t heard anything since then. I sent an email 3 days ago following up to see if there was anything else regarding credentialing or licensing. No return email. I am waiting to resign until I hear from them, but need to start preparing for a move to a different company. What’s the protocol? Should I call HR? Am I worried for nothing?

Comment: If you want a realtime answer, email is the wrong medium. Pick up a phone and call them.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I call HR?

Yes, if you want to get the fastest answer. They won't punish you or withdraw the offer for making that phone call.

Did they tell you how long it would take for them to get back to you after you took the physical ?

For example, if they had told you that they would let you know the result and the next steps after 3 weeks, then perhaps, you should probably wait for 3 weeks before contacting them (unless you have some very urgent deadline).

---

BTW, you are absolutely right that you should not resign until you have the official answer and official offer from the new company.